# How do you do List/Detail Editing with a UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, master-detail

What's the best way to have a list of text items, tap on one and be able to edit it? How about going to a detail view? But then how do you get your change back into the UITableView?

I suppose this could all be done with SQL or CoreData but since the UITableView is based on an array, can we just edit that element of the array and reset the table view?

Eventually I want the data to be persistent so I'll probably go with CoreData or SQL but for now I just want to go from a list to details, edit the details, and go back to the list.

Comment: There are many ways: navigation controller, modal view etc.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a specific sample. I made a UITableView that leads to a detail UIView. The selected text from the table makes it to a text field on the detail view but I can't get any edits to that text back into the table view. Any concrete ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

"But then how do you get your change back into the UITableView?"

Both the table view and the detail view should be accessing a common model object. In other words, the detail view that's changing data doesn't have to even know the table view exists.

Answer (score 0):

Look up protocols.  Basically you have a class that has information to share.  In this case it will be your detail controller or some sort of data object as mentioned above.  Have this class (with the info to share) declare a protocol that uses that information.  The method should use parameters to sneak out your information.   The class also declares a 
    id (less than)protocol(greater than) delegate 
where "protocol" is what you declared above.

Now in this class when you obtain the information that you want to share (however you do it) send the delegate method message to your delegate.  `[delegate informationObtained:newInfo]`.

For the class or classes that need this information, implement the protocol method(s). The information you need is being passed by the parameters to the method. It's the same way you use `TextFieldDelegate` and `UIPickerFieldDelegate`, only you decide the protocol and you decide how to implement them. Here's a code example

In SpeakHereController.h

```
@protocol SpeakHereControllerDelegate
-(void)newSoundCreated:(NSString *)newSoundName savedFile:(BOOL)savedFile element:  (id)element;
-(void)cancelNewSound;
-(void)soundEdited;
@end
```

in the interface:
    id  delegate;
don't forget the @property, make it (non atomic, assign)

In the implementation file, 
once I have the information I want to share:

```
[self.delegate newSoundCreated:myFileName  savedFile:self.savedFile element:self];
```

Now for the tableview controller that wants to use this information:
in the .h file declare that you are going to implement the protocol

```
@interface AlarmSoundsTableViewController : UITableViewController <SpeakHereControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Then in the implementation file implement the method:

```
-(void)newSoundCreated:(NSString *)soundName savedFile:(BOOL)savedFile element:(id)element
{

    [self setSoundFileName:soundName];
     ...
```